# Работа метода принудительной сборки мусора

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора

Встретил на просторах интернета вот такой метод:

```
public void ClearMemory()
        {
            //Free up Precious Memory
            GC.AddMemoryPressure(50000);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.RemoveMemoryPressure(50000);
        }
```

Разъясните, если не сложно, алгоритм его работы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если посмотреть в хелп, то все стает на свои места.

Вначале говорим среде - сейчас будет выделение 50к (да, я знаю, это очень много:)) ). И [Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) - "начинай делать сборку мусора", хотя среда и не обязана начать ее прямо сию секунду. Для этого поставили [WaitForPendingFinalizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers(v=vs.110).aspx) - подождать, пока уборка завершиться. Дальше - аналогичные танцы с бубном, но ждут полную уборку.

В справке пишут, что Collect "Принудительно запускает немедленную сборку мусора для всех поколений." - в этом свете троекратный его запуск выглядит абсурдным.

Я думаю, что этот код придумал юный подаван, который не осилил нормального программирования и балуется дотнетом. Либо он нужен для того, чтобы последущий за ним критический участок кода не прерывался GC.

В любом случае, если Вам нужен такой код, значит Вы что-то делаете неправильно - например, используете алгоритмы, которые генерируют много мелких объектов, или просто используете неподходящий для задачи язык.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Мне просто стало интересно, зачем городить такой код. А принудительную сборку мусора вызывал только два раза в своих проектах, первый раз, когда только делал первые шаги и работал с большими xlsx-файлами штатными средствами, второй совсем недавно - при работе с библиотекой захвата видео с web-камеры, и то вполне достаточно было в таймере вызывать GC.Collect(); единожды. Поэтому и заинтересовался подобным кодом.